# Why my menu is not hierarchical?

Tags: php, hierarchical

I want to create a hierarchical menu. The function:

```
/*
* Table has 3 fields: `ID`, `PARENTID` and `NAME`
* `ID` is unique, `PARENTID` showing his parent node id.
* This function will go through it and build unordered list and call itself when needed to build subitems.
* $level argument used to define wich node's subitems to build. Default is 0 which is top level.
*/    
function showMenu($level = 0) {

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `menus` WHERE `submenu` = ".$level); 
echo "<ul>";
    while ($node = mysql_fetch_array($result)) { 
        echo "<li>".$node['name'];
        $hasChild = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `menus` WHERE `submenu` = ".$node['id'])) != null;
        IF ($hasChild) {
            showMenu($node['id']);
        }
        echo "</li>";
    }
echo "</ul>";
}
```

I've found on a stackoverflow in a similar question.

I have a table `menus`:

```
+----+----------------+---------+
| id | name           | submenu |
+----+----------------+---------+
|  1 | FIRST HEADER   |    NULL | 
|  2 | SECOND HEADER  |    NULL | 
|  3 | THIRD HEADER   |    NULL | 
|  4 | (fh) submenu 1 |       1 | 
|  5 | (fh) submenu 2 |       1 | 
|  6 | (fh) submenu 3 |       1 | 
|  7 | (sh) submenu 1 |       2 | 
|  8 | (sh) submenu 2 |       2 | 
|  9 | (th) submenu 1 |       3 | 
| 10 | item 1         |       4 | 
| 11 | item 2         |       4 | 
+----+----------------+---------+
```

I used this function in script

```
showMenu(4);
```

and here is the result:

```
<ul><li>item 1</li><li>item 2</li></ul>
```

as u can see, there is no word about even a piece of hierarchy, just a couple of items in source. What possibly wrong in my code?

Comment: Can you output the queries you are using?

Comment: it's only with empty arguments: SELECT * FROM `menus` WHERE `submenu`=0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are specifically requesting just the submenu number `4`.

If you just call `showMenu()` with no arguments, it will show the entire menu tree.

Comment: unfortunately is not so. Empty list.

Comment: Ah, that's because your "top-level" entires have `NULL` for a submenu. Either edit them in the database to have `0` instead, or adjust the code to use `IS NULL` rather than `=0`

Comment: cool! Indeed, I was thought that that is the reason before, but I forgot to update my table with zeroes... Thank you! and btw I didnt see a reason for minuses on my question.

Comment: "Too localised" is what you're currently being downvoted for.